# Shader with alpha masking other objects

Tags: three.js, shader

I'm trying to make a very simple shadow shader which consists of a plane with a shader showing a radial gradient on colors and alpha.

Beneath this shadow lies another plane with the same kind of shader but linear.
And as a background of all this, a linear gradient from dark blue to light blue.

[image: Shadow with the correct transparency]

The problem is that when my camera approaches the ground, the plane of the shadow masks the floor.

[image: Shadow with the incorrect transparency]

Why does it happen and what can I do to prevent that?

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-sun-po9j3
https://po9j3.csb.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to post code to check for sure but it likely happens because three.js sorts the order it draws things based on the center of the objects and their distance from the camera.

You can force a different order by setting `Object3D.renderOrder`

three.js also generally draws opaque things before transparent things so my guess is your ground plane and your shadow plane are both set to `transparent: true` but the ground can be set to `transparent: false` in which case it will be drawn first.

You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-shadows.html) useful. It shows a similar example.

As for why there is a hole it's because of the depth buffer. If something in front gets drawn first then the pixels behind are not drawn. So if the shadow happens to be drawn first it ends up looking like a hole because the pixels of plane behind it are not drawn.

See [this](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-transparency.html)

Comment: Setting the renderOrder of my shadow plane to 1 fixed the issue. But I still don't understand why rendering the ground after the shadow makes an hole in it.

Comment: Updated the answer to mention the hole

Comment: Is it for the same reason that the shadow plane is flickering during a camera movement? While this plane is slightly above the ground and now has a renderOrder set to 1?

Comment: I added my code in the question. On the second link, you, you can see the flickering by playing with the camera position on the Y axis.